# How to Connect already running bitcoind in AWS to Insight API in different AWS Server

Tags: bitcoin-core, bitcoind, bitcore, blockexplorer, bitpay

Need to create a bitcoin explorer using bitcoind. I am using bitcore and insight API for this purpose.

Currently running bitcoind in AWS Server with all port open. Need to connect this running bitcoind with bitcore and use insight-api and UI in different server.

This my ***bitcore-node.json*** file:

```
    var configuration = {
 datadir: '/home/.bitcoin',
 network: 'testnet',
 services: [
   {
     name: 'bitcoind',
     module: Bitcoin,
     config: {
       spawn: {
         datadir: '/home/.bitcoin',
         exec: '/home/Downloads/bitcoin-0.16.1/bin/bitcoind'
       }
     }
   },
   {
       name: 'web',
       module: Web,
       config: {
           port: 4001
       }
   }
 ]
};
```

This is my **bitcoin.conf**

```
server=1
testnet=1
whitelist=127.0.0.1
txindex=1
addressindex=1
timestampindex=1
spentindex=1
zmqpubrawtx=tcp://127.0.0.1:28332
zmqpubhashblock=tcp://127.0.0.1:28332
rpcallowip=127.0.0.1
uacomment=bitcore
```

Need to Connect the Insight API to in the A server to Bitcoin in B server.

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: How to connect the two servers ?

Comment: You don't need bitcoind and bitcore, bitcore is already a node.

Comment: @JBaczuk : Referring the following link [Source] (https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/62929/connect-already-running-bitcoind-with-bitcore-for-bitcoin-explorer). How to proceed with the Connecting the Insight API with the Bitcoin Node.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow the instructions on this [README](https://github.com/bitpay/insight-api). It should install **bitcore** (the bitcoin full node implementation by Bitpay), **insight-api**, and **insight-ui**. The instructions are:

```
npm install -g bitcore@latest
bitcore create mynode
cd mynode
bitcore install insight-api
bitcore install insight-ui
bitcore start
```

If that doesn't sync with the bitcoin network and start showing blocks, then please share some logs/errors and we can help you further.